# InDesign CC 2018 on EPUB export is expanding image sizes WAY beyond original document dimensions

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub, ibooks-author

My InDesign document is 1,200px wide by 1,920px tall. Whenever I export the document as an EPUB (fixed) the graphics are scaled to a size MUCH larger than this. It's preventing me from uploading to the iBook store.

For example, a rectangle at 1,200px by 637px is becoming **5,000px by 2,177px**.

My export conversion settings are... `format:automatic` `resolution:72` `format method:progressive` `image quality:maximum`

Any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, I would say the resolution of your InDesign document is 300 dpi, the normal resolution for print. The ratio between 72 dpi and 300 dpi is 4.16 recurring, and that is the same ratio as between 1,200 and 5,000.

If your InDesign document is 300 dpi and you tell it to export at 72 dpi, it will apparently add all the pixels present, but with a much lower dpi, giving a very large end result.

The solution may be as simple as changing the document resolution to 72 (if that doesn’t have the same effect, only in the document itself)—alternatively, export at 300 dpi, unless there’s some specific reason to export at 72 dpi.